# Laravel CORS middleware fails for post and resource request

Tags: laravel, post, laravel-5, resources, cors

I've been trying to solve this problem for a while, but unable to crack it.

I've a Laravel Backend and angular frontend. These are on different domains as the frontends need to be a web and mobile cordova app.

Even after adding CORS middleware, post and resource request fail to load and I get a

```
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

error in console.

The following get request does work fine :-

```
Route::get('example', ['middleware' => 'cors', function(){
    return Response::json(array('name' => 'Steve Jobs 1', 'company' => 'Apple'));
}]);
```

But following ones fail -

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function () {
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function()
{
    Route::resources('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
    Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
});
});
```

I am following https://scotch.io/tutorials/token-based-authentication-for-angularjs-and-laravel-apps.

My CORS.php

```
class CORS
{
/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, Origin'
    ];
    if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        $response->header($key, $value);
    return $response;
    return $next($request);
}
}
```

kernel.php

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{

protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
    /*\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,*/
];


protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
    'cors' => 'App\Http\Middleware\CORS',
];
}
```

Comment: Can you post what HTTP response code your request returns? I was having a similar problem recently and my responses were returning a code of 500, an internal server error. Turned out it had nothing to do with my headers but the fact that I was not doing CSRF correctly. Disabling CSRF made it work. Maybe try that and see if it is truly a CORS problem or something else like in my case?

Comment: Okay I see where you disable CSRF so it's not that. Still, knowing the HTTP response code could give some insight.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem for hours now. Tried different solutions (used the [barryvdh/laravel-cors library](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-cors), made my own CORS middleware, added headers in the index.php file) but nothing helped me out.

Now I'm using https://github.com/neomerx/cors-illuminate and it works.

One of the differences between the cors-illuminate library and the laravel-cors library is in the installation guide.
At the cors-illuminate guide it explicitly says that you have to add the middleware line directly after

```
\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
```

Maybe the laravel-cors library would work also, if you add the Middleware directly after the CheckForMaintenanceMode Middleware. Didn't try it out.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Seems it has something to do with post request headers after the token is granted to a user. jwt adds in an authorization header and a cookie]
Seems it has something to do with post request headers after the token is granted to a user. jwt adds in an authorization header and a cookie

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use the following to temporarily get around it:

I added in the cors middleware in my controller construct like so:

```
      public function __construct()
   {
       // Apply the jwt.auth middleware to all methods in this controller
       // except for the index method.
       $this->middleware('jwt.auth', ['except' => ['index']]);
       $this->middleware('cors');

   }
```

in my kernel:

```
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,

    'jwt.auth' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\GetUserFromToken::class,
    'jwt.refresh' => \Tymon\JWTAuth\Middleware\RefreshToken::class,
    'cors'=> \Barryvdh\Cors\HandleCors::class


];
```

this appears to be working for me. Also, check your laravel log and debug your controller. I had a typo in my controller and the http response in my client console was the cors error.

Comment: did you check your storage/logs/laravel.log ? because if there is any syntax error in your controller, the client message will still say:(index):1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8000/api/v1/partner. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9001' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was that I was executing calls which envolved the request before autenticate with jwt.
I had this code that cause the problem:

```
function store(Request $request)
{
    $producto = new Producto($request->json()->all());
    $this->currentUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
    $producto->cliente_id = $this->currentUser->cliente_id;
    $producto->save();
    return json_encode($producto);
}
```

As you can see, JWTAuth line was before a line which uses $request.
You can either move the JWTAuth line to forst line in function or create a constructor in the class like this:

```
function __construct() {
    $this->currentUser = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
}
```

and that solved the cors issue.
I use Barryvdh Cors.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing something similar. It worked out fine after I edited the .htaccess file in public directory. Below is the htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Let me know if this solution works for you

Make sure to enable headers in htaccess by running

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

Answer (score 0):

The Cors handler is a built-in feature in the latest Laravel version using this package https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

Answer (score 0):

So I was having the same problem and spent hours debugging and figuring out what was wrong when I was using my own CORS middlewares in api.php without using the fruitcake one (barryvdh/laravel-cors).

After hours of debugging and frustration I figured out that when you use a middleware in a group, then it doesn't get applied right away.

### **How laravel matches routes and "applies" middlewares:**

When you send a request, laravel reads the api.php and just "registers" all the routes and middlewares and "remembers" them without actually executing them. After it "registers" all of them (reads the whole `api.php` file), it executes a function where it inputs the path from the URL and the HTTP method that was used in the request and then it begins to find the route that matches the URL and HTTP method and after it finds one, it executes those middlewares that this route is located in and then it executes the controller methods.

So for example with your code when you send a `GET` request to `/api/authenticate`, it matches the resource method `index` and then executes the middleware `cors` and therefore it works and returns data from your controller.

### **Why POST, PUT, DELETE and PATCH don't work with this approach:**

When you send a `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE` or `PATCH` request to `/api/authenticate`, the browser sends an `OPTIONS` request first, so laravel "registers" all the routes and then it executes the "matching" using the URL and the HTTP method (it is `OPTIONS` right now).

But there is no route that has a method of `OPTIONS` and `resources` don't have an `OPTIONS` method either, so since there is no route that has an `OPTIONS` method, laravel doesn't match anything and therefore it does not execute those middlewares where you eventually handle `OPTIONS` methods.

> `api.php` example
>
> ```
> Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function () {
>   Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function() {
>      Route::resources('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController', ['only' => ['index']]);
>      Route::post('authenticate', 'AuthenticateController@authenticate');
>   });
> });
> ```

#### **The matching function in Laravel:**

The "matching" function is called `findRoute` and it is located in `vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php`.

> ```
> /**
>  * Find the route matching a given request.
>  *
>  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
>  * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
>  */
> protected function findRoute($request)
> {
>     $this->current = $route = $this->routes->match($request);
>
>     $this->container->instance(Route::class, $route);
>
>     return $route;
> }
> ```

When you log `$route` with `error_log(json_encode($route), 0);`, then make a `GET` request and then look in error logs, you can see the succesful "match" and that it applied the `cors` controller:
`{"uri":"api\/authenticate","methods":["GET","HEAD"],"action":{"middleware":["cors"],"uses":"App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthenticateController@index","controller":"App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthenticateController@index","namespace":null,"prefix":"api","where":[]},"isFallback":false,"controller":null,"defaults":[],"wheres":[],"parameters":[],"parameterNames":[],"computedMiddleware":null,"compiled":{}}`

But when you send a `PUT` request, this happens:
`{"uri":"api\/authenticate","methods":["OPTIONS"],"action":{"uses":{}},"isFallback":false,"controller":null,"defaults":[],"wheres":[],"parameters":[],"parameterNames":[],"computedMiddleware":null,"compiled":{}}`

There you can see that actually `OPTIONS` method was sent (because browser sends an `OPTIONS` method first) and nothing got matched and no middleware was applied and therefore the `PUT` request failed with a CORS error (`Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`)

## **The summary and solution:**

- Middlewares in `$routeMiddleware` array get applied **after** Laravel succefully matches a route with the path and the HTTP method because different routes can have different middlwares.
- Middlewares in `$middleware` array (global middlewares) get applied **before** Laravel begins registering and matching routes.

To solve it, you **have to** use a global middleware in `$middleware` array, that handles the `OPTIONS` method. You can just use the [Fruitcake](https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors) one that handles it and then you can use your own CORS middlewares in `api.php` that can set different headers to your liking (for example different Allowed Origins for different routes/groups/prefixes.

Comment: Thanks you @SenTisso great explanation but in Laravel 9 CorsHandler middleware is applied to global middleware out of the box. All my options are set to "*" yet I am getting CORS error. I am accessing my remote server from http://localhost:8080.

Answer (score 0):

For the cors, i recommend to use this package.
https://github.com/fruitcake/laravel-cors

But, if you have high number of request. It is better to configure the cors in nginx or apache level. There will be nginx can serve large number of request than php-fpm so, it will optimize the performance.